# File is marked as Ignored by TFS everywhere plugin, but in fact it is not

Tags: eclipse, team-explorer, team-explorer-everywhere

While adding for the first time files to TFS2012 some of them where suggested to be ignored (like .dll's, exe's etc.)

In fact some of those suggested to ignore files I need in TFS. So I've explicitly removed them from the ignored list and added them to TFS.

Now in Visual Studio I can work with those files normally but not in Eclipse! In Eclipse they are still labeled as "Ignored" and all team functionality is disabled! :(

Is there a way to solve this problem??

P.S. Of course those files are not in the .tfignore.

**ADDED:**

Ignoring seems to be done based on the file extension (.dll) and the folder name (\bin).

Comment: What do your `.tpignore` and `.tfignore` files look like?  Sometimes an errant regex in `.tpignore` can wreak havoc.

Comment: @Thomson. I do not have .tpignore file on my disk at all, and .tfignore has no special entries. just few folders (like \jre, \doc, etc.) are ignored.

Comment: So you didn't tell `.tfignore` *not* to ignore DLLs?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Certain files (such as `DLL`s) are [ignored by default](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tfs/ms245454%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#tfignore) in Team Foundation Server local workspaces.

In order to override the default ignore state, you will need to set a `.tfignore` line that specifies that `DLL`s should not be ignored.  From the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tfs/ms245454%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#tfignore):

```
# Do not ignore .dll files in this folder nor in any of its sub-folders
!*.dll
```

Comment: the file is called `.tpignore`, not `.tfignore`

Comment: @HenriqueSousa: it's not, they are two different files.  `.tfignore` is the new-for-TFS-2012 ignore file for local workspaces, shared by both Team Explorer Everywhere and Visual Studio clients.  `.tpignore` is used only by Team Explorer Everywhere.  In this case, I'm talking about `.tfignore`.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification, indeed we still use TFS 2008 together with Team Explorer Everywhere and the `.tpginore` file serves our needs in Eclipse.