# How to include DLL files in a specific folder with TFS2012

Tags: tfs

I saw on a Microsoft forum that I can create a .tfignore file and place it in the root folder.
I have a folder named `Libs` and it contains DLL files that I want to keep under source control. How can I use the .tfignore file to include my `Libs` folder in source coutrol?

Comment: possible duplicate of [File is marked as Ignored by TFS everywhere plugin, but in fact it is not](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13818522/file-is-marked-as-ignored-by-tfs-everywhere-plugin-but-in-fact-it-is-not)

Answer (score 6):

You can negate inherited rules in a .tfignore file.  In your case, try adding a .tfignore file to your Libs subdirectory with the following content:

```
\# Do not ignore .dll files in this folder nor in any of its sub-folders
!*.dll
```

The not (!) operator essentially reverses the rule and says "do indeed include these files types."

For more details see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms245454.aspx.  Look at the sections titled ".tfignore file rules" and ".tfignore file example"